# Orchard CMS - Can't Set up Tenants from the Command Line

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying ot figure out how to create an orchard tenant site though the cli.  I have found a few resources on the web, and they don't seem to work for me, or I am not using the commands correctly

My main site is called landlord, and i want to create a tenant site called tenant1.  I have enabled multi-tenancy, and created several through the orchard landlord site, and I was able to set them up without any issues.

My steps:

Open up `cmd` window in bin folder, and type `orchard`, and that does an initilization, and gives me an orchard command prompt

The command that i found on the web is

Orchard.exe tenant add mytenant /Host:mytenant.mysite

I try to run

```
tenant add tenant1 /Host:tenant1.landlord
```

and this gives me an error that switch `/host` is not found

if I instead use

```
tenant add tenant1
```

it seems to work, as it says
creating tenant1...

I am not sure what exactly is supposed to happen with this command, but I can't see the tenant site listed in the landlord site, and I am unable to setup the site through the CLI

The command I found for setup is

```
Orchard.exe setup /t:mytenant /SiteName:mytenant.mysite
  /DatabaseTablePrefix:mytenant /AdminUsername:admin
  /AdminPassword:password  /DatabaseProvider:SQLServer
  /DatabaseConnectionString:"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Orchard;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password"
```

I took the connection string that I used to setup the landlord site, and there is no way I can get this to work.

```
setup /t:tenant1 /SiteName:tenant1.landlord
  /DatabaseTablePrefix:tenant1 /AdminUsername:admin
  /AdminPassword:password /DatabaseProvider:SQLServer
  /DatabaseConnectionString:"server=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;database=dbname;user id=user; pwd=thepw"
```

The error is:

```
No such host is known

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such host is known

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception: No such host is known]


[SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while estab
lishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessib
le. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured t
o allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is
known.)]
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdent
ity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, O
bject providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean
redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData r
econnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTra
nsientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOp
tions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConn
ectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
```

I have already used the connection string, and I can access the db fine.

Not sure why either command is not working

Now that I go back to the browser to load my landlord site, it seems to be not working, and i get the error

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\...\...\App_Data\Sites\tenant1\Settings.txt' is denied.
```

This is from the root that previously loaded my landlord site, I think that i have totally destroyed my site

Can anyone let me know the correct commands to use, and maybe where i went wrong?

Update

thanks, I used your advice and i was able to get my landlord site up and running again.  Using your instructions, i was able to create a tenant through the cli (tenant2).  Now I am have a problem viewing the tenants through the Landlord admin page, I get the error:  Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot....\App_Data\Sites\tenant2\Settings.txt' is denied.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot....\App_Data\Sites\tenant2\Settings.txt' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost) at Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettingsManager.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Orchard-1.10.3\src\Orchard\Environment\Configuration\ShellSettingsManager.cs:line 54 at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettingsManager.Orchard.Environment.Configuration.IShellSettingsManager.LoadSettings() in C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Orchard-1.10.3\src\Orchard\Environment\Configuration\ShellSettingsManager.cs:line 23 at Orchard.MultiTenancy.Controllers.AdminController.Index() at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

Thanks

Comment: That commands looks correct, but I think once you blew one setup you put the site in a broken state. It would have been best to reset that tenant by deleting `App_data\Sites\tenant1` before trying again. And of course, make backups.

Another thing to consider is access right that could explain why that connection string works in some contexts but not here. You might want to try with a command line running as administrator and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: thanks, I used your advice and i was able to get my landlord site up and running again.  Using your instructions, i was able to create a tenant through the cli (tenant2).  Now I am have a problem viewing the tenants through the Landlord admin page, I get the error that I added to the original post

Comment: As you can see in the error message, the web site doesn't have the write access it needs to the `App_Data` directory. You need to grant that access to the user the web site is running under. This is detailed in this doc topic: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Setup/#capability-check-and-known-error-cases

Comment: FYI, I just made that into an answer...

Comment: I was able to solve my permissions issue with the file settings.txt.  I have to manually add permissions to the settings.txt for the iis_iusrs .  I find this strange for a couple reasons, the iis_iusrs has full access to the folder \App_Data\Sites\tenant2 where the settings.txt file is stored.  I need to figure this issue out, or it sort of defeats the purpose I have for creating sites with the cli. Is there a way to make sure the settings.txt file gets the required permissions?

Comment: Make sure the `App_data\Sites` folder has the permissions, and that they are recursively applied.

Comment: I agree with you, and this is the confusing part,  i have given the iis_iusrs full control to the app_data folder, and i have checked the permissions on the sites folder, and iis_iusrs has full control.  But when I create another tenant site, and check the security on the settings.txt file there is no listing for the iis_iusrs user.  Hmm, and I get the same error as before.   Also, I am running the cmd as an administrator.

Comment: Also check the app pool the web site is running under, for impersonation, user, etc. Re-apply permissions if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I checked the app pool is  using the ApplicationPoolIdentity user.  Should it be set to something else like LoacalService user or NetworkService user instead?  Also, for the site in iis, under authentication I have enabled impersonation.  That said any new site that i create with the cli is missing iis_iusrs permissions for the settings.txt .

Comment: That's a different IIS question. There are different valid ways of configuring IIS, it depends on your hosting requirements. Impersonation can be problematic in this context however, because you're telling IIS to run under the authenticated user. In general, the answer is that the same user the IIS process is running under should have the rights you need (in this case, write to app_data). If you enable impersonation, it means you need rights for all potential authenticated users of your site. That is... dangerous. So yes, probably don't enable impersonation.

Comment: I'd also say that impersonation is a remnant of that long gone era when Windows authentication was a useful thing on a web site or intranet. Now, we have better methods of authentication, so I don't see a valid scenario where you'd use it nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

If your web site gets into a broken state because of a bad tenant addition, you can delete that tenant by deleting its directory under `App_Data\sites`. When setting-up a new tenant, you also need to make sure the user under which the process for your web site is running has sufficient rights to:

- access the database (that you as a user can reach the database doesn't necessarily mean the web site will)
- write to `App_Data`